# asp.net web.config appsettings multiple values

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have `appSetting` block that looks like this:

```xml
<appSettings>
  <key="site1" value="http://www.thissite.com,site name" />
  <key="site2" value="http://www.thissite.com,site name" />
</appSettings>
```

I want to populate a dropdown list with the values and text:

> value="http://www.thissite.com" text="site name"

I can get them into individual arrays using this:

```
string[] mykey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["site1"].Split(',');
string[] mykey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["site2"].Split(',');
```

however, I want to combine them into one array and then loop through and populate the dropdown in the codebehind. I can populate it this way looping through the individual arrays, but it just seems as if there must be a better way with less code.

Can anyone tell me how?

---

credit to you all but many thanks to [acermate433s' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6526788/238722) below.

```
NameValueCollection appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
    for (int i = 0; i < appSettings.Count; i++)
    {            
        Response.Write(appSettings.GetKey(i).ToString() + "-" + appSettings[i].ToString());
    }
```

Obviously, I will do a bit more than just display it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AppSettings is a **NameValueCollection**, you could loop through all of its values using **for each**

Comment: thanks that is awesome saved me loads of code. i'll edit my question with a little example. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the config file by creating custom configurations.
Essentially you will end up with :

```
<site name="key1">
   <address value="...1..." />
</site>
```

https://web.archive.org/web/20201202223151/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/020707-1.aspx

Alternatively, you could specify the key as the name of the site and just use http://cephas.net/blog/2003/09/26/extending-webconfig-in-aspnet/ sort of thing.

Comment: If you structure the custom config correctly, you won't need to parse a comma delimited string either.  You'd have separate elements or attributes for the name and url

Comment: jglouie, can you give example of how to set that up

Answer (score 2):

Just to give full working sample as this question keeps getting hits

```
NameValueCollection appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

for (int i = 0; i < appSettings.Count; i++)
{
    string key = appSettings.GetKey(i);
    string value = appSettings.Get(i);  
}
```